# A variable in the while loop doesnt change

Tags: python, variables, while-loop, self-organizing-maps

I am doing a Self Organized Map in python like in [this](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html) tutorial. It partially works however I encountered a wierd problem in one of my while loops. Here is the code for the problem part:

```
radius = 15    
while radius > 2:
            #print(radius)                    
            while checkW < targetImage.w:
                while checkH < targetImage.h:
                    #print(radius)
                    nodeDistance = math.sqrt(math.fabs(bmuW - checkW) * math.fabs(bmuW - checkW) + math.fabs(bmuH - checkH) * math.fabs(bmuH - checkH))
                    if(nodeDistance <= radius):
                        theta =  math.exp((-1) * ((nodeDistance * nodeDistance) / (2 * radius * radius)))
                        targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w0 = targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w0 + theta * 0.1 * (inputR - targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w0)
                        targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w1 = targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w1 + theta * 0.1 * (inputG - targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w1)
                        targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w2 = targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w2 + theta * 0.1 * (inputB - targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w2)
                        targetImage.canvas[checkW,checkH].r = int(targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w0 * 255)
                        targetImage.canvas[checkW,checkH].g = int(targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w1 * 255)
                        targetImage.canvas[checkW,checkH].b = int(targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w2 * 255)                    
                    checkH =  checkH + 1
                checkH = 0
                checkW = checkW + 1
            radius = radius - 1
            #print(radius)
```

`radius` is initially set to 15 on each pixel iteration and the idea is to set the r,g,b values according to the radius, reduce it and set new r,g,b values and so on. Note that calculating radius is different than `radius = radius - 1` in the algorithm but I wanted to test it with something simple.

My problem is that in the first and the third `print(radius)` I get the expected values 15,14,13,12... etc. But in the middle one I always get 15 which is the initial value. I do not understand why `radius` does not change at that point while it changes on the other points. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You sure it's not just that printing `radius` inside the loop prints each value of `radius` a crapton of times, and you didn't look far enough down the output to see it change?

Comment: Also, you really ought to look into `for` loops. `while` loops with manually adjusted counters are highly error-prone.

Comment: Why do you do `checkH = 0` right after `checkH =  checkH + 1` (without anything in between)?

Comment: Basically checkW and checkH moves on a matrix and make changes on the r,g,b values accordingly. So for a 40x40 image it goes like (0,0),(0,1),(0,2)... when checkH value reaches 40 I need to reset it to zero so that it becomes (1,0),(1,1),(1,2)...

Comment: Also yes I did check the whole log and every value of radius is 15 for the middle print(radius)

Comment: Please provide a [short, self contained, runnable example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. Currently, I can't run your code, because `checkW`, `checkH`, `bmuW`, `bmuH`, `inputR`, `inputG`, `inputB`, `math`, and `targetImage` are not defined. Are there any lines here that you can delete, without changing the fact that the bug is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that I missed a cruicial part in the loop. `checkW` and `checkW` are not reset to zero after each radius iteration so the loop would run only once for `radius = 15`. After adding `checkH = 0` and `checkW = 0` at the end of the radius iteration it fixed the problem and my SOM works perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
 while radius > 2:
        #print(radius)                    
        while checkW < targetImage.w:                
            while checkH < targetImage.h:
                #print(radius)
                nodeDistance = math.sqrt(math.fabs(bmuW - checkW) * math.fabs(bmuW - checkW) + math.fabs(bmuH - checkH) * math.fabs(bmuH - checkH))
                if(nodeDistance <= radius):
                    theta =  math.exp((-1) * ((nodeDistance * nodeDistance) / (2 * radius * radius)))
                    targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w0 = targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w0 + theta * 0.1 * (inputR - targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w0)
                    targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w1 = targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w1 + theta * 0.1 * (inputG - targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w1)
                    targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w2 = targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w2 + theta * 0.1 * (inputB - targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w2)
                    targetImage.canvas[checkW,checkH].r = int(targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w0 * 255)
                    targetImage.canvas[checkW,checkH].g = int(targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w1 * 255)
                    targetImage.canvas[checkW,checkH].b = int(targetImage.canvas[checkW, checkH].w2 * 255)                    
                checkH =  checkH + 1
            checkH = 0
            checkW = checkW + 1
        radius = radius - 1
        checkH = 0
        checkW = 0
        #print(radius)
```